# Internet relay using XBee modules

Tags: ip, ethernet, tcp, xbee, ppp

I'd like to use two Xbee modules for a point-to-point Internet relay.

Something like this:

eth0(host1) <-> Xbee(1) <-> ... <-> Xbee(2) <-> eth0(host2)

Setting up a serial connection with Xbee is simple (I'm using two Arduino boards).

But how do I get TCP/IP to Serial? So I guess my main problem is this here:

TCP/IP <-> Serial <-> ... <-> Serial <-> TCP/IP

How can I do this?

I guess I have to setup PPP or SLIP for that - but have no clue how to do that.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1055

Comment: Get PPP working between the devices using a wired serial port, with hardware flow control and a baud rate of about 115200.  Then replace the wire with paired XBee radio modules.  Or look at the XBee Internet Gateway (xig) project as a simpler solution to Internet access via XBee radio.